# In a software update states report in SCCM (MS Updates), what's the difference between "Compliant" and "Successfully Installed Updates"?

Tags: sccm

Just wondering what the difference is.

Answer (score 4):

I may be a little rusty on this, but I believe that "Successfully Installed Updates" mean that the scripts run successfully, and the patch is installed. The status becomes "Compliant" after the update agent processes/verifies the state of the update.

It may take awhile to see "Compliant", depending on how often you run inventory, and how many mobile devices that you have. (ie. Off-network devices may not run inventory scans)

Answer (score 0):

Compliance category provide the best interface for finding the software updates that are required on client computers.

Successfully installed- updates installed on client computers.

Answer (score 0):

Successfully Installed is self explanatory. Clients which are compliant with updates, may not necessarily have them installed if the updates were not applicable to them.